# How to extract date and time from ISO into local date and time

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, datetime, momentjs

I have a date and time in ISO

```
"time": "2021-10-28T17:30:00.000Z"
```

Below is what I am doing right now to extract the date and time:

```
var dateExtract = time.substring(0, 10);
var timeExtract = time.match(/\d\d:\d\d/);
```

But it is giving me the exact date and time written in ISO.

What I want is to extract the date and time in local date and time. I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Date instance.

```js
let obj = {"time": "2021-10-28T17:30:00.000Z"}
const dateTime = new Date(obj.time);
const date  = dateTime.toLocaleDateString().replace(/\//g, '-');
// '28-10-2021'
const time = dateTime.toLocaleTimeString()
// '18:30:00' since I am in (+1)
```

Also find a pool of answers in this similar [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Answer (score 1):

Just create a date object and use [toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) or [toLocaleDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) or
[toLocaleTimeString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString)

```js
const date = new Date("2021-10-28T17:30:00.000Z")
console.log(date.toLocaleString())
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString().replaceAll("/","-"))
console.log(date.toLocaleTimeString())
```

Comment: Sir, also how to get local time?

Comment: See updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You are getting dates in a wrong method.
when you are reading the date it should be converted to your locale, so that you will get exact date from UTC date

You can use JS Date() function or moment library

```
let d = new Date("2021-10-28T17:30:00.000Z")

d.toDateString()

d.toLocaleDateString()
```

check Date functions to get date, month, year, time , seconds or timestamp

refer [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp

Or you can use the external moment library
https://momentjs.com/